# Where did the walking stick come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In Sherlock S04E02, at the mortuary we saw John hit Sherlock in the face and as a result he was admitted in the hospital. Then John gave his own walking stick to Sherlock, as a parting gift.

[image]

> JOHN: Parting gift.
>
> (He braces it against the back of the chair.)
>
> NURSE CORNISH: Oh, that’s nice. A walking stick.
>
> JOHN: Yeah, it was mine from ... a long time ago.
>
> Source: http://arianedevere.livejournal.com/

Though it was pre-equipped with a recording device, as per *Sherlock's forecast*. John doesn't use his walking stick anymore and Sherlock was asleep on the hospital bed. Throughout the entire episode neither John nor Sherlock is carrying the stick so how come John gave him the stick? Where did it come from in the first place?

Comment: I was going to answer this and then realised I couldn't... I assume that Sherlock took it while they live together (or perhaps John left it behind when he moved out) but can't back it up with anything from the shows.

Comment: Sherlock enjoys his disguises.  It seems reasonable to assume that he might have retained the stick as a potential prop and then taken advantage of it in this episode.

Answer (score 1):

If you watched the entire episode - they go thru and 'show' how it was done. The cane keeps coming back. Believe is part of a running joke as Sherlock kept it after John didn't use it anymore. Sherlock had been right - John NEVER needed it. But in this case. The cane came in handy.